# Light from hdri sky box not reflecting on object

Tags: texturing, light, hdri

[image: When I added the hdri to the environment the light from the skybox wouldn't show up on my object]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. There is something that you are doing wrong - that is certain. However without you providing more information and/or the .blend file it is impossble to say with certainty what exactly it is.

Comment: sorry about the small photo this was the biggest it could be that stack exchange would accept

Comment: The screenshot is fine. It is very difficult to understand your problem as you have not provided information about how you ended up in this situation. It seems as if the object's materials did not have anything connected to their material output nodes, however surely that would be the first thing you would check before asking the question, wouldn't it? There is a number of other possibilities that would be clear to most people who decided to try to help you in literally 5 to 10 seconds after opening the .blend file. That is if you shared it of course.